# Failed to setup WeMo SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk

I was trying to integrate iOS SDK into my app by following the steps in the demo app. 
But, in my app "discoveryManager:didFoundDevice" is not getting called.

The log generated by my app looks incomplete:

```
2014-05-16 00:43:16.255 [8361:60b] ssid = 2WIRE891
2014-05-16 00:43:21.648[8361:60b] ssid = 2WIRE891
2014-05-16 00:43:21.649[8361:60b] refreshListFromSDK
2014-05-16 00:43:21.667[8361:60b] initWithUdnList =(
):(
):(null)
2014-05-16 00:43:21.683[8361:60b] discoverDevices call starts
2014-05-16 00:43:21.684[8361:60b] restartControlPoint entering.
2014-05-16 00:43:21.686[8361:60b] restartControlPoint lock.
2014-05-16 00:43:21.693[8361:60b]  
2014-05-16 00:43:21.695[8361:60b] Multicast searchForDevices retry:1
Multicast searchForDevices DONE Timelapse: 3.009840
```

I would really appreciate if you could point me to some documentation or tutorial.

Thanks,
Shah

Comment: Is the wemo setup able to give commands remotely....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue, the fix is to copy the DeviceConfigData.plist file from the WeMo demo app into your app.